# Jquery validate (styling the errors inside table)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have a form with Jquery .validation().

Form:

```
<form....>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td>Name: </td>
<td><input type='text' name='Name'/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Last Name: </td>
<td><input type='text' name='LastName'/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Address: </td>
<td><input type='text' name='Address'/></td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type='submit' name='enter' value='submit'/>
</form>
```

I would like to print errors like this:

[image]

Is it possible?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: @ManseUK sample code please, or just an idea how to do it. :))

Answer (score 1):

[Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/kMfV3/)

**HTML**

```
<form name="test">
<table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
<tr>
<td>Name: </td>
<td><input type='text' name='Name'/>
    <span class="error_span">Enter name</span>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Last Name: </td>
<td><input type='text' name='LastName'/>
        <span class="error_span">Enter last name</span>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Address: </td>
<td><input type='text' name='Address'/>
        <span class="error_span">Enter address</span>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type='button' id='submit' name='enter' value='submit'/>
</form>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit").click(function(){
        $('input').each(function(index) {
                   if($(this).val()=="") {
                       $(this).addClass("has_error");
                       $(this).siblings(".error_span").show();
                   }else{
                       $(this).removeClass("has_error");
                       $(this).siblings(".error_span").hide();
                   }
          });
    });
 });
```

**CSS**

```
.error_span{
color:red;
    display:none;
}

.has_error{
 border:1px solid red;
}
```

[Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/kMfV3/)

You can use `onsubmit` attribute of your form to execute the javascript and stop the form from submitting if there is validation error

Answer (score 0):

You can do in Two ways..

1)

```
<form....>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td>Name: </td>
<td><input type='text' name='Name'/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Last Name: </td>
<td><input type='text' name='LastName'/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td>Name Is Required</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Address: </td>
<td><input type='text' name='Address'/></td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type='submit' name='enter' value='submit'/>
</form>
```

or

2)

```
<form....>
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
    <td>Name: </td>
    <td><input type='text' name='Name'/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Last Name: </td>
    <td><input type='text' name='LastName'/> <br />Name Is Required</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Address: </td>
    <td><input type='text' name='Address'/></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <input type='submit' name='enter' value='submit'/>
    </form>
```

Comment: This looks cool, actually i know that, but do you have any ideas how to achieve that jquery validate actually post the error labels like that?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use custom validation code for doing like that. Check this link. http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/addMethod